# How to recover deleted yum.repos.d in Centos OS?

Tags: centos, yum, centos8

I accidentally deleted the yum.repos.d on centos 8(version centos-release-8.0-0.1905.0.9.el8.x86_64.rpm) and since then I am observing

```
**Error:There are no enable repos**
```

I tried to `yum reinstall http://vault.centos.org/8.0.1905/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/centos-release-8.0-0.1905.0.9.el8.x86_64.rpm` but I am observing the message

```
"Could not find the host".
```

Anybody kind enough to help me out?

Edit:

I got the "Could not find host" part resolved, I am getting "SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL" instead now.

If it cannot be reversed, can anyone help me to install Python2 without yum or dfn. That will also do for me.

Comment: When are you seeing the error messages? Can you add some more context to what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to restore the `yum` repository configuration by reinstalling the related package via `rpm`:

```
rpm -iv --replacepkgs http://vault.centos.org/8.0.1905/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/centos-release-8.0-0.1905.0.9.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Hi, just one word - GOD. Thanks a lot. You saved me.